# Asignar teclas a un formulario

Tags: c#

tengo este codigo para asignar dos letras del teclado a un formulario

El codigo funciona bien pero lo que necesito es agregar a cada caso la tecla ctrl, es decir que funcione si el usuario presiona la tecla ctrl + la tecla L, lo mismo para la tecla M.
Muchas gracias

```
private void fjdCentros_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.L:
                this.tcCentros.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;

            case Keys.M:
                this.tcCentros.SelectedIndex = 1;
                break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de KeyEventArgs, existe la propiedad [Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.control?view=netframework-4.8) que aclara si la misma fue presionada junto con la tecla o no.

Esa propiedad es booleana y si viene en true, entonces quiere decir que la tecla CTRL fue presionada.

Para usarlo, dentro de tu case podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
case Keys.L && e.Control:
```

O podrias controlar antes de entrar al switch, si la misma se presiono:

```
if (e.Control) 
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
    ....
```